# SwiftUI view present UIKit ViewController errors

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, swiftydropbox, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Many times, we are required to open a view that is required to be presented from a `UIViewController` in a SwiftUI view. Prominent examples of such being `UIDocumentInteractionController` and less prominent ones being SwiftyDropbox to open a login screen of Dropbox in Safari for authentication. The common technique is to create a `UIViewController` on demand in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` subclass and present view controller from it. But it has never worked for me.

```
struct DropboxView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

   @Binding var isShown : Bool

   func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context)  {
    
     if isShown {
        let scopeRequest = ScopeRequest(scopeType: .user, scopes: ["files.content.write"], includeGrantedScopes: false)
  
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromControllerV2(
            UIApplication.shared,
            controller: uiViewController,
            loadingStatusDelegate: nil,
            openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil) },
            scopeRequest: scopeRequest)
       }
    }

   func makeUIViewController(context _: Self.Context) -> UIViewController {
       return UIViewController()
   }
}
```

When I invoke such a view from a SwiftUI view using modifier such as:

```
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDropboxLoginView) {
        DropboxView(isShown: $showDropboxLoginView)
    }
```

I get two errors:

```
Cannot use Scene methods for URL, NSUserActivity, and other External Events without using SwiftUI Lifecycle. Without SwiftUI Lifecycle, advertising and handling External Events wastes resources, and will have unpredictable results.
```

and

```
Attempt to present <SwiftyDropbox.MobileSafariViewController: 0x107919600> on <UIViewController: 0x105a2f130> (from <UIViewController: 0x105a2f130>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

I wonder how to present such view controllers from within SwiftUI view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this setup you don’t need `fullScreenCover` just use the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

```
DropboxView(isShown: $showDropboxLoginView)
    .frame(width:0, height: 0)
```

Put it anywhere in the `body`.

Both the `fullScreenCover` and `DropboxClientsManager` seems to be using the root.

Comment: I have a List inside my body and a button to present this view, where do I put it inside my body?

Comment: @DeepakSharma put it in the background of your button or the background of the label in the button. It doesn’t really matter since the parent view controller is empty it just has to be in the body somewhere.